# "There is no disk in the drive" in an application that doesn't require it

Tags: windows

Our application is written in C++ and used on Windows XP. On some client machines with only a C: drive, an error pop ups when the application starts:

*There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive "D"*

If they hit "Continue" or insert a CD (even an empty one!) and press "Try Again", everything works fine.

[Someone suggested](http://liquidrescale.wikidot.com/forum/t-25337) that this might be related to compiling on drive D: (our build machine uses drive D: for compilation). Has anyone encountered this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would certainly be a good idea to find out what's trying to access the D drive and fix it. But it's possible to suppress this behaviour, if desired, with a call to [SetErrorMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680621(VS.85).aspx) using the SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS flag. It may even help you to identify the problem, because the error will be sent directly to the application instead of being handled with a system dialog.

Answer (score 3):

Try compiling it on C: and see if the error still exists. You can use *Process Monitor* from [www.syinternals.com](http://www.syinternals.com) to see which file/dir the program is trying to access. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

This may be old news but I was receiving the same error just now trying to run Delphi 2010.  It turns out that when I unplugged my cellphone that I was charging, the error went away.

Since I charge my phone all the time on this computer, I wondered why all of the sudden this was happening.  One thing different this time was that my phone was plugged in when I restarted the computer to install some updates.

After unplugging the phone (after restart) the error disappeared and I plugged my phone back in to charge without incident.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This error was driving me nuts until I realized that it was being caused by my inserting a 3-slot USB memory card reader with only 1 card in it.  I still haven't found how to intercept the windows message, though.

Comment: Yes. It's caused by some device with drive letter assigned but GetDrive can't access this. Is there any way to get rid of this pop-up?

Answer (score 2):

Try running the program through [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), and see if there's any reference to D: in the binary's dependencies. This might give you a hint to which library (if any) is being problematic. Or it might give you nothing, but it's free and very quick to do, so I'd recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes, we used to have errors like these ... unfortunately i can't tell you what the fix was but it was something utterly stupid, that much i remember. I could still find the comment in our CDebugStackWalk class, so it may have to do with stack unrolling ... somewhere, somehow...